# How to get documents that were updated in the last hour from firestore?

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement full text search of firestore DB by using Elasticsearch.

In order to sync the firestore data to elasticsearch, I used cloud functions with Firestore update events, such that whenever a firestore document is updated, a cloud function is triggered which updates the elasticsearch.

This works as expected. However, this is not cost effective.

I would like to update the elasticsearch periodically every hour by querying the firestore DB for documents that changed in the last one hour and updating elasticsearch.

Is there a way to query firestore for only those documents that got updated in the last hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have a field in the database that reflects when the document was last updated.  Without that, you can't build a query to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but in order to achieve this you could add a field to your documents in firestore like "indexed": boolean and run a cron on cloud functions that query docs with indexed == false and then after indexing change them to true.